# Firebase Security rules wildcards [syntax version 2] question

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I read the official documentation of Firebase Security Rules. But I came across a text that was hard to understand. Please confirm if I understood the following quote correctly

> In version 2 of the security rules, recursive wildcards match zero or
> more path items. `match/cities/{city}/{document=**}` matches documents
> in any subcollections as well as documents in the `cities` collection.
> You must opt-in to version 2 by adding `rules_version = '2'`; at the top
> of your security rules:
>
> ```
> rules_version = '2';
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Matches any document in the cities collection as well as any document
>     // in a subcollection.
>     match /cities/{city}/{document=**} {
>       allow read, write: if <condition>;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

This quote from this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#version-2)

### **Question**

If I understood correctly this quote:

> In version 2 of the security rules, recursive wildcards match zero or
> more path items. `match/cities/{city}/{document=**}` matches documents
> in any subcollections as well as documents in the `cities` collection.

That quote means: that `match/cities/{city}/{document=**}` matches to `/cities/LA` and `/cities/LA/landmarks/landmark1` paths in requests. Because in `/cities/LA` example recursive wildcards match to zero as said doc quote:

> In version 2 of the security rules, recursive wildcards match zero or
> more path items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That quote means: that `match/cities/{city}/{document=**` matches to `/cities/LA` and `/cities/LA/landmarks/landmark1` paths in requests. Because in `/cities/LA` example recursive wildcards.

Yes, that is exactly what it does. You can read documents from the `cities` collection, as well as from the `landmarks` sub-collection. Recursive wildcards mean that your security rules will allow you to read documents from the top-level collection and will fall to the deepest sub-collections.

Comment: If I get you right, that means, that rules which added to `match/cities/{city}/{document=**` a applied to `/cities` level, `/{city}` level, and any sub-collections or documents levels?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That's why we use recursive wildcards.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly in Firebase Security Rules of version 1, recursive wildcards behave differently. And the same rules of `match /cities/{city}/{document=**}` in version 1 will be applied only to any sub-collections or documents levels. But not applied to `/cities` level and `/{city}` level. See example in [sub-Question two] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779629/firebase-security-rules-wildcards-version-1-questions)

Comment: If those questions are related to another question, then you should add them there, and not to this question. Can I help you with other information regarding this question in particular?

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot. I would be grateful if you could help me with another question similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779629/firebase-security-rules-wildcards-version-1-questions

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.